# populating dropdown menu from xml file using c#

Tags: c#, .net

i am suffering to get output showing in drop down menu from the xml file which have content like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wayList>
<way xsi:type="Check" Name="mountainway" />
<way xsi:type="Check" Name="railway" />
<\wayList>
```

and want output as

- mountainway
- railway

please suggest 
thank you

Comment: where are you getting stuck? reading the file contents? binding the contents to the dropdown?

Comment: Also a pointer for asking a good question, mention the technology you are using (either in a tag or at least in the question self). Is that ASP.Net, WinForms, WPF etc...

Comment: I cannot read the desired output data from the xml file. I stuck with code to to populate the drop down menu from that xml file using xmldocument().

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("books.xml");
 while (reader.Read()) 
 {
// Do some work here on the data.
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader.Name, reader.Name));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use LinqToXml.

```
List<string> values = XDocument.Load(filename)
                      .Descendants("way")
                      .Select(w => w.Attribute("Name").Value)
                      .ToList();
```